# Suggestion needed for best way to call context.done()

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I have written the event hub function as follows.
Please suggest if I am doing any mistake here while calling context.done(), as I am using async function here.

I am asking this question because I am worried if I lose data

```
const config = {
    endpoint: "..",
    key: "...",
    databaseId: "..."
};

module.exports = async function (context, IoTHubMessages) {
    context.log(`Last Motor On: ${JSON.stringify(IoTHubMessages)}`);
    var output = []
    var outputLastMotorOn = []
    const client = new CosmosClient({
        endpoint: config.endpoint,
        key: config.key,
    });
    ...
    IoTHubMessages.forEach(async function(iotmessage){
        let deviceId = iotmessage["deviceId"]
        
        const querySpecLastDevData = {
            query: " ... "
        };
        const { resources: itemLastDevData } = await containerMyCollection.items
            .query(querySpecLastDevData)
            .fetchAll();

        if (itemLastDevData && itemLastDevData.length && itemLastDevData.length == 2) {
                ...
                context.log("lastMotorOnParam", lmo)
                context.bindings.lastMotorOnParam = lmo
            
        }
    })
    context.done();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As your function code is asynchronous there is no need to explicitly call context.done(). You can go through [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#exporting-an-async-function) for additional details.